# Trigger Responsiveness based on Parent's element Width not on Window DOM's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'd like to trigger the responsive approach for bootstrap when its Parent container is on certain size, the Children will response accordingly.

> i.e if container is `< 1200` , Children elements will transform to
>   **MD** instead of just remaining to **LG**

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mq1b8qyd/12/)

1. Resize on fiddle at least `1200` pixels for the red bordered container called `#page-content-wrapper`

[image]

2. Click the `Toggle Menu` button which makes the `#page-content-wrapper` to a `950` pixels that is considered to be an MD in bootstrap, forms should transformed to MD also but remains to LG

[image]

> 3. Here is my intended output after clicking the `Toggle Menu` button. The `#page-content-wrapper` is less than 1200 which is MD then , the
>      Children elements transforms into MD.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `col-md-12` on `<div class="col-lg-12">`

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you're gonna have to go with the javascript way. There is no way for media queries to know the dimensions of an element.

When setting the toggle, you could use javascript/jquery to remove some classes, depending on whether the new element width is smaller or larger than the breakpoint.

However, doing this makes you lose the media query functionality, so when resizing the window, it will not respons anymore. You could circumvent this by listening to the `onresize` event as well.

### This is what I came up with:

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/mq1b8qyd/8/

Note that I added the `.respond-parent` class to the element that needs to respond to it's parent's size.

It's also not the cleanest solution, but in the example you provided, it works. If things get more complicated, then you'd need different classes like `.respond-parent` depending on the required widths.

**Javascript**

```
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

function checkWidth() {
  var wrapperWidth = $('#page-content-wrapper').outerWidth();
  var $responsiveParent = $('.respond-parent');
  $("#page-content-wrapper h2").text("The width for the #page-content-wrapper is " + wrapperWidth);

  alert('checking width: ' + wrapperWidth);
  if (wrapperWidth >= 1200) {
    $responsiveParent.attr('class', 'respond-parent col-lg-12');
  } else if (wrapperWidth >= 992) {
    $responsiveParent.attr('class', 'respond-parent col-md-8');
  } else if (wrapperWidth >= 768) {
    $responsiveParent.attr('class', 'respond-parent col-sm-6');
  } else {
    $('.respond-parent').attr('class', 'respond-parent col-xs-12');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var wrap = $("#page-content-wrapper").outerWidth();

  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
  $('#wrapper').bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I don't really get the last line of code. Why is it on `#wrapper` and the **transitionend ** thing ?  Please enlightened me

Comment: It makes sure that `checkWidth()` executes after the menu has slided in, so the width is checked after the animation. If you do it straight away, you'll get the element width before the animation is done, and thus it will be wider/narrower than the end state. The listener is on the `#wrapper` because that's where you defined the transitions in your CSS file.

Comment: Please use console.log. Alert is annoying.

Comment: Not a great solution, but a solution... and there's not a lot of information about this on the web sooo... interesting. It would be great if we could use the responsiveness like iframes content do using media queries, but without those iframes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this now

https://jsfiddle.net/mq1b8qyd/9/

I removed the `position: absolute;` on `#page-content-wrapper`
and removed the `toggled` class of the sidebar, so initially the sidebar should be hiding

Comment: Hi Sir, 

It doesn't matter if sidebar is initially hiding or not. Sorry If I haven't explained it clear. The form inputs (children) should responsively transformed if the #page-content-wrapper (parent) resizes it's width.

i.e
#page-content-wrapper is 865  => input forms should be transformed to SM 

#page-content-wrapper is 615  => input forms should be transformed to XS

fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/mq1b8qyd/10/


Though this solution might be correct, but I want other approach.